# Juju bootstrap fails with "Temporary failure in name resolution" using Amazon AWS

Tags: server, juju, amazon-ec2

I have followed the instructions over at https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/config-aws.html to try and setup myself with a juju environment.

It all seemed to setup alright. SSH keys, Gererate config, repository, adding access id and secret keys to environments.yaml file. 
Although my key file from aws IAM management console was called credentials.csv rather than rootkey, I couldn't find that link described in the documentation.

When I give the command `juju bootstrap` in the [testing page](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html#test). It fails giving me the error:

```
juju bootstrap ERROR Get https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/juju-gobblygookmynukmbersinhere/provider-state: lookup s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

(note I just replaced my numbers for this posting my actual terminal has my numbers in.

This is my first attempt at any ec2 work so I have gone in and created new IAM profiles. What have I done wrong?

Any help would be great. I think I'm in over my head!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so it turns out the ubuntu server I was running the juju commands on wasn't setup properly.

It had a static IP address, gateway and netmask but no dns name-servers listed.
There was no resolution to any dns requests.
I added the the dns-name servers and it all went swimmingly!

Thanks heaps for checking in. I hope listing my resolution here can help someone out one day!